# How do I access self from UIAlertAction in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I want to navigate back to root view controller when someone says ok to the alert action. But the Alert action does not allow to access self.

What is the work around to get current navigation controller in AlertAction,

here is the code,

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "IQ", message:"Thank you for your feedback!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Menu", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
UIAlertAction in
NSLog("OK Pressed")
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true) //error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way instead:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to define a getter for the `okAction` property.

```
var okAction: UIAlertAction {        
    get {
        return UIAlertAction(title: "Menu", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in Xcode 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss the presented view controller (the Alert) before you try to pop from the navigation controller.